# When I click one specific row of table it should display that specific row details in new tab. How to do it in Vue.js? I m new to JS as well as Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frameworks

Here below is my Vue code of child component and parent component it will display the employee details which is fetch from api in table format which we can click specific row.

when I click on specific row how to display that complete row details in new tab?
I m new to javascript and vue.js please help me how to do this...

here is child component EmployeList.vue

```
<template>
    <div>

        <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <table border ="1px" id="tableData">
           <tr>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td>Salary</td>
             <td>Age</td>
           </tr>
           
           <tr  v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.id">
            <td><el-link type="primary" href="" target="_blank" onclick="myFunction()">{{item.employee_name}}</el-link></td>
            <td>{{item.employee_salary}}</td>
            <td>{{item.employee_age}}</td>

           </tr>

           
    
        </table>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
Vue.use(axios,VueAxios)


    export default 
    {
        name:'EmployeList',
        props: ['employeName','employeSalary','employeAge'],
        data()
        {
            return{list: undefined,}
        },

        mounted()
        {
            axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then((resp)=>
            {
                this.list = resp.data.data;
                console.warn(resp.data.data)
            })
        },
        methods:
        {
            myFunction()
            {
                
             
            }
        }
    }
</script>



<style scoped>

</style>
```

and here is parent component index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   
    <EmployeList />
    
    
 
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import EmployeList from '../components/EmployeList.vue'




export default {
    name: "Index",
    components: {EmployeList},
    data(){
      return {
        name:'Vishwas',
        channel: 'CodeEvolution',
      }
    },

}
</script>


<style>
#app{
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;

}


</style>
```

Comment: so u don't know js and u go directly to use vue?

Comment: Would be better to learn javascript first, then frameworks. If you are new to JS, someone wrote this code for you :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@click` to handle the click event on the table row, so you should add it to `<tr>` like this:

```html
<tr @click="doSomething">
....
</tr>
```

And now you should define `doSomething` in the `methods`:

```
export default {
   ...
   methods: {
      doSomething () {
         // Put what you want to do here
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Now you want to open a new tab, you can do this with `window` object in js like this:

```
window.open('http://example.com')
```

Furthermore, you should send the row id that clicked to a new tab, so you can define an `argument` in your function like this:

```html
<tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" @click="doSomething(item.id)">
....
</tr>
```

```
export default {
   ...
   methods: {
      doSomething (id) {
         window.open('http://example.com/showDetail?id='+id)
      }
   }
   ...
}
```